# Delete custom master page error on feature deactivation

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have a feature that deploys custom master pages to all sites in a site collection on activation, and want to delete all traces of the custom master pages on deactivation.  On deactivation, after setting the site's masterpage back to v4.master, an error (Cannot remove file "custom.master". Error Code: 158.) occurs when trying the delete the custom master page that was previously set as the default.  The feature doesn't finish deactivating after the error, but most of the files are deleted and the branding is already set back to v4.master.  When trying to deactivate the feature again, it removes the final file custom.master without error.

I don't understand what's missing.  Why does FeatureDeactivating() have to finish before custom.master can be deleted?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPSite sitecollection = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = sitecollection.RootWeb)
        {
            string WebAppRelativePath = sitecollection.ServerRelativeUrl;
            if (!WebAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                WebAppRelativePath += "/";
            }

            foreach (SPWeb site in sitecollection.AllWebs)
            {
                site.CustomMasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
                site.MasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
                site.UIVersion = 4;
                site.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPSite sitecollection = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = sitecollection.RootWeb)
        {
            string WebAppRelativePath = sitecollection.ServerRelativeUrl;
            if (!WebAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                WebAppRelativePath += "/";
            }

            foreach (SPWeb site in sitecollection.AllWebs)
            {
                site.CustomMasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master";
                site.MasterUrl = WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master";
                site.UIVersion = 4;
                site.Update();

                WebAppRelativePath = site.Url;
                if (!WebAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    WebAppRelativePath += "/";
                }
                SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(site.Url + "_catalogs/masterpage/images/");
                if (folder.Exists)
                    folder.Delete();
                folder.Update();

                SPFile file = web.GetFile(site.Url + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.css");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.Delete();
                file.Update();

                file = web.GetFile(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/html5.master");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.Delete();
                file.Update();

                file = web.GetFile(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master");
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    file.Delete();  // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
                }
                file.Update();

                /*file = web.GetFile(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.Delete();
                file = web.GetFile("/_layouts/minimal.master");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.CopyTo(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/");

                file = web.GetFile(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/default.master");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.Delete();
                file = web.GetFile("/_layouts/default.master");
                if(file.Exists)
                    file.CopyTo(WebAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/");*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not dispose SPSite objects from properties of a feature. Also do not dispose SPWeb from SPSite.RootWeb. Only from SPSite.OpenWeb().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to get a new reference to the `SPWeb` and use this to call `SPWeb.GetFile()`.

The `SPWeb` from the `using` block may still have a reference to custom.master and will need to be refreshed.

Comment: Trying to do the same thing as OP... does that mean outside the `SPWeb` `using` block, I create another `using` block for a new `SPWeb`? Or should I do it inside the first `using` block? If I can figure it out or you can help me out, I'll have another upvote for you

Comment: Create a new `using` block for the new `SPWeb` object. If you want a more detailed answer or if it is still not working create a new question and post some code as you'll get more eyes on your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing it in a different module (deleting the assets only once the feature was uninstalled, not when it's deactivated). My question is whether the new `using` block would be inside the existing one, or after the existing `using` block? might put it in your answer to be explicit (?)

Comment: I would put it outside the `using` block as it would be easier to read the code and see what is going on, also it would ensure that you don't accidentally use the original `SPWeb` instead of the newly created one. It may not actually make any difference but I haven't tested that and it's best to play it safe.